# Using window[] to access variable contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set content in my main div based on the variable name. For example, if I run: `changeMain(nearbyCows)` I want to see 'tehe', instead it seems window[page] is undefined. Any ideas why?

```
function changeMain(page) {
    var nearbyCows = "<a>tehe</a>";
    var nearbyChickens = "<b>lol</b>";
    var search = "<i>meh</i>";

    $("main").html(window[page]);
}
```

Comment: `nearbyCows` is a local variable in this function. It's not in the scope of the caller, unless it has its own variable with the same name.

Comment: You can only use `window[name]` to access _global_ variables, not local variables.

Comment: @A.Wolff The value of page could be one of three, nearbyCows, nearbyChickenso or search (otherwise it would fail to set the html)

Comment: Why does the question have a down vote?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating this variables in the scope of the function.  The properties of `window` refer to the global scope.  If you want to use the global scope like this, then you need to move your variable declarations out of the function:

```
var nearbyCows = '<a>tehe</a>';
var nearbyChickens = '<b>lol</b>';
var search = "<i>meh</i>";
function changeMain(page) {
    $("main").html(window[page]);
}
```

But, then your essentially just using the `window` as a look up hash, and it would be better and cleaner to keep your own look up object instead of co-opting global.

for example:

```
var MainChanger = {
    nearbyCows: '<a>tehe</a>',
    nearbyChickens: '<b>lol</b>',
    search: "<i>meh</i>",
    change: function(page) {
        $('#main').html(this[page]);
    }
};

MainChanger.change('nearbyCows');
```

Answer (score 0):

`var nearbyCows` is not defined on global scope but as local variable, use then: `nearbyCows = "<a>tehe</a>";` without using directive `var`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an object, not separate variables:

```
function changeMain(page) {
    var items = { nearbyCows: "<a>tehe</a>",
                  nearbyChickens: "<b>lol</b>",
                  search: "<i>meh</i>"
    };
    $("#main").html(items[page]);
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
changeMain('nearbyCows');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must know that there is multiples type of variable.

You have the global variable which is assign the the window (not a good practice). You can declare it like that :

```
window.varName = ...;
window['varName'] = ...;
varName = ...;
```

There is variable scope, that is the usual way to declare variable :

```
var varName = ...;
```

Those variables are accessible by inner scope aswell but not accessible by outer scope.

There is also object properties. You create an object and assign value :

```
var obj = {};
obj.varName = ...;
obj['varName'] = ...;
```

If you can see, there is no way you can access a scoped variable with a dynamic string, you need object or global variable. :

```
function changeMain(page) {
    //Global variable, not recommended
    window.nearbyCows = "<a>tehe</a>";
    window.nearbyChickens = "<b>lol</b>";
    window.search = "<i>meh</i>";

    $("main").html(window[page]);
 }
```

or :

```
var obj = {} //Declare outside if you want to access it outside the function
function changeMain(page) {
    // var obj = {}; //or inside if you want it to be a private variable
    //Object properties, recommended
    obj.nearbyCows = "<a>tehe</a>";
    obj.nearbyChickens = "<b>lol</b>";
    obj.search = "<i>meh</i>";

    /*Alternative declaration, faster to process :
    obj = {
        nearbyCows : "<a>tehe</a>",
        nearbyChickens : "<b>lol</b>",
        search : "<i>meh</i>"
    }*/

    $("main").html(obj[page]);
 }
```